# JWPlayer appending to playlist on the fly

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

Is there a way in jwplayer to actually have an interactive playlist, where a user can append/remove songs to the current playlist and jwplayer will respond to these changes.  I'm aware of using jwplayer().load(playlist), but that restarts the entire playlist.

Comment: I'm afraid when you add an item it will interrupt playback.